# How to create a route for a guest user page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a central routes config file that holds all of my routes. So far, the routes config consists of routes for my dashboard pages. Here is what it looks like:

```
const routes = [
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Dashboards",
    key: "dashboards",
    icon: <Icon fontSize="small">dashboard</Icon>,
    noCollapse: "true",
  },
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Tools",
    key: "apps",
    icon: <Icon>apps</Icon>,
    collapse: [
      {
        name: "First Page",
        key: "first",
        icon: <Icon>apps</Icon>,
        href: `first_page`,
      },
      {
        name: "Second Page",
        key: "second",
        route: "/",
        component: <SecondPage/>,
      },
      {
        name: "Third Page",
        key: "third",
        icon: <Icon>table</Icon>,
        href: `third_page`,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Settings",
    key: "settings",
    icon: <Icon>settings</Icon>,
    href: `settings`,
    noCollapse: true,
  },
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Sign Out",
    key: "signout",
    icon: <Icon>logout</Icon>,
    href: `sign_out`,
    noCollapse: true,
  },
];
```

This is how I am rendering the routes in `App.js`:

```
      <Routes>
        {getRoutes(routes)}
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
      </Routes>
```

This is how I am looping over the `routes` list:

```
  const getRoutes = (allRoutes) =>
    allRoutes.map((route) => {
      if (route.collapse) {
        return getRoutes(route.collapse);
      }
      if (route.route) {
        return <Route exact path={route.route} element={route.component} key={route.key} />;
      }
      return null;
    });
```

I want to add a new route for a guest user form to the project that can be accessed by an unauthenticated user, meaning they shouldn't be able to access the dashboard pages. But I'm not sure whether it should be nested somewhere in the `routes` config file or I should create it like this in `App.js`:

```
      <Routes>
        {getRoutes(routes)}
        <Route
          exact
          path="/guest_user"
          element={<GuestUser/>}
          key={"guest"}
        />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
      </Routes>
```

Note: names have been amended for explanation purposes.

Comment: `collapse` doesn't appear to be anything special, just children routes to render, and there's no `route` properties defined in the `routes` config object. You might have an easier time rendering your routes using the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes) hook. Other than this, it's rather up to opinion where any other routes are placed and rendered. In other words, your question is a little off-topic. What have you tried? Were there any specific issues with either implementation?

Comment: If you want to protect routes, you can conditionally depending on the authentication state (user), render the page. If the condition is false (not a user) **Navigate** to the guest page

Answer (score -1):

You can create a **ProtectedRoute**.js file/folder where you can write the logic as follows.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function ProtectedRoute(props) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
  const { Component } = props;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    if (!token) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  });
  return <Component {...props} />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

After that you can do the following changes in **routes array** just like this.

```
{
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Profile",
    key: "profile",
    icon: <Icon fontSize="small">person</Icon>,
    route: "/profile",
    component: <ProtectedRoute Component={Profile} />,
  },
```

Other functionalities could be added like role based etc. in the ProtectedRoute.js .